# Simulate / Automate fingerprint scan

Tags: appium, ui-automation

Is it possible to simulate / automate fingerprint scan feature on Android device/ emulator using Appium /Ui-automation or any other tool ?

I came across some development is going on on this feature simulation on emulator API level >=23 [link](https://github.com/appium/appium-adb/pull/146).

Is anyone aware of the development news ? or Does anyone has more pointers on this topic ?

Comment: I don't think so this is a good place to ask for a "news." You shall porbably give it a try yourself.

Comment: @nullpointer agree. But many people doesn't know about this implementation. They will know if they read. And most important if someone knows then we will get idea to do it.

Comment: which would have been the case on you trying as well.